# Divide images into blocks and compare each corresponding block

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Hi I have a set of images of size 200x200 and I want to divide these images into 10 blocks of size 20x20(each image). After the images are divided into blocks,

1) I want to compare 1st block of image 1 with 1st block of image2, image 3 and 2nd block with 2nd block of image2, image 3 and so on.

2)After comparing blocks the block with maximum value should be used and put in a final image such that the final image has blocks with maximum value from image1, image2 or image3.

Is it possible to do such comparison and produce a new image.

```
image = cv2.resize(im,(200,200))
image1 = cv2.resize(im1,(200,200))

hs = round(h/10)
ws = round(w/10)
hs1 = round(hs1/10)
ws1 = round(ws1/10)
resized = cv2.resize(image, (ws,hs), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
resized1 = cv2.resize(image1, (ws1,hs1), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

The result is like as shown in the picture [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eUutdgZeX6FeBv6DJlhUaP7nQXl1aTaU)

Images can be accessed [here](http://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cl0RPsO3LooQ4pJSTToRO_oqSUAKZNg_).

Comment: If you divide a 200x200 image into 20x20 blocks, you will get 100 blocks, not 10, surely? Please add a couple of the images to your question and an indication of what the result should look like.

Comment: How do you compare a 20x20 block with another one? That's 400 pixels, or 1,200 values if the image is RGB, so what are you actually comparing and what will the result be?

Comment: I want to compare the blocks with other blocks. I am able to compare the images pixel by pixel(pixel intensities). But I want to compare the blocks. One approach I thought was to take a mean of each block and compare it with all the corresponding blocks of the images. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I have added some information to my answer - is that how you expect the result to look?

Comment: @MarkSetchell is it possible to produce the output image as the original images. This is what i got when I used ```numpy.maximum.reduce() ```. But i was expecting that after the comparison the final image would be like the original images(like a normal image)

Comment: I don't see any `numpy.maximum.reduce()` in your code. If you have code, please add it to your question. Please also answer my questions in the comments - it wastes too much time writing code to implement something that is unclear and then changing it again. Please click `edit` under your question and add in all the necessary details there - not in the comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A hint to get you started... you don't need to tile your image up and create resized/cropped sub-images to do this. You can perfectly easily access your blocks *in situ*. Here is an example, with smaller blocks (so you can see them) to get you started.

```
import numpy as np

# Make synthetic ramp image
ramp = np.arange(6,dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1,1) + (np.arange(8)*10).reshape(1,-1)
```

That looks like this:

```
array([[ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
       [ 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71],
       [ 2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72],
       [ 3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73],
       [ 4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74],
       [ 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75]])
```

Now let's look at the top-left 2 rows and 3 columns:

```
print(ramp[:2, :3])
```

That looks like this:

```
array([[ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 1, 11, 21]])
```

And let's get their average:

```
print(ramp[:2, :3].mean())
10.5
```

Now let's look at the bottom-right 2 rows and 3 columns:

```
print(ramp[-2:, -3:])

array([[54, 64, 74],
       [55, 65, 75]])
```

And get their mean:

```
print(ramp[-2:, -3:].mean())
64.5
```

---

A second hint... your answer will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what the ```ramp = np.arange(6,dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1,1) + (np.arange(8)*10).reshape(1,-1)``` did. Did it just divide the image into 8x10 blocks? And does it return the coordinate position of the blocks?

Comment: No, it just generates the synthetic "image" you can see on the line that follows - you didn't provide sample images...

Comment: You can access them here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cl0RPsO3LooQ4pJSTToRO_oqSUAKZNg_

Comment: Is it possible that the current output you mentioned can be formed in the form of the original images?