# Convert multiple images to array and find the mean

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Hi I am trying to convert multiple images to an array of block structures and then I want to find the average of each block. I came across a solution for a single image but I don't know how to implement it for multiple images. The solution mentioned can be seen [here] ([Divide image to blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315111/divide-image-to-blocks/58315301?noredirect=1#comment102991997_58315301))!
I want to implement the same for multiple images. Is that possible?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("your_file.jpg", "r")
arr = np.asarray(image)
arr = np.split(arr, 20)
arr = np.array([np.split(x, 20, 1) for x in arr])
mat = [arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(40) for j in range(40)]
```

This is not my code. I have referenced the original author @Daniel from where I got the idea. His code works for a single image. Is there a way to use it for multiple images all at once?

I have tried it but I am not sure if it right way to do it.

```
img = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("resized/*.jpg")]
X=[]
for im in img:
    arr = np.asarray(im)
    arr = np.split(arr, 20)
    arr = np.array([np.split(x, 20, 1) for x in arr])
    mat = [arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(20) for j in range(20)]
    X.append(mat)
```

Comment: can you add some of your code here ? so that its easy to reproduce and find solution

Comment: This appears to be the same question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58281897/2836621

Comment: Why can’t you use a loop?

Comment: I have tried but I am not sure if it is the right way. I'll post it here so that anyone can point out if I am wrong